# Unable to restart postgres service via GCP?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

while updating some data references I have started getting "out of shared memory" error and as a hint, they have asked to increase max locks per transaction so tried to update to max limit but that operation failed and after that I am not able to connect to Postgres even it is not allowing to restart the service.

Comment: What is in the log? What exact change did you make?

Comment: I tried to update max locks per transaction db flag to its max value

Comment: What is `dynamic_shared_memory_type` set to? What is the operating system and PostgreSQL version? What is the error message in the PostgreSQL log?